# Sufficient conditions for differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

A well-known theorem about sufficient conditions for differentiability is the following:

> Let $f: U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function, $\hat{x}_0\in\text{int}(U)$ and $r>0$ such that $B(\hat{x}_0,r)\subseteq U$, if for all $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exist for all $\hat{x}\in B(\hat{x}_0,r)$ and is continuous at $\hat{x}_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $\hat{x}_0$.

A version of this theorem with a less number of hypothesis is proven in my textbook:

> Let $f: U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function, $\hat{x}_0\in\text{int}(U)$, $r>0$ such that $B(\hat{x}_0,r)\subseteq U$, if for all $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}-\{k\}$ we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exist for all $\hat{x}\in B(\hat{x}_0,r)$ and is continuous at $\hat{x}_0$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$ exists at $\hat{x}_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $\hat{x}_0$.

So I was wondering if the same is true if we reduce the number of partial derivatives that exist and are continuous in $B(\hat{x}_0,r)$, if so, what is the minimum number of partial derivatives that have to exist in $B(\hat{x}_0,r)$ and be continous at $\hat{x}_0$, for the function being differentiable at $\hat{x}_0$? (if we suppose that the rest of them exist at $\hat{x}_0$ and the number of partial derivatives that we reduce is less than $n$)

Comment: The number cannot be reduced. You certainly know a function on $\Bbb R^2$ with 2 partial derivatives existing at some point and which is not differentiable at that point. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429913

Comment: @AnneBauval Sure, but this example satisfies the hypothesis trivially, sorry if I didn't clarify it, the number of partial derivatives that we reduce is less than $n$.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question. Didn't you want to reduce the number to less than $n-1$? This example proves it is not possible to reduce it to $n-2$ (in the example, $n=2,$ but you can trivially deduce from it an example for arbitrary $n$).

Comment: The condition "less than $n$" is artificial and just obscures things. Having less than $n-1$ partial derivatives continuous already opens the doors to counterexamples (i.e. non-differentiality). At the end of the day, take your favourite counterexample with $n=2$ and both partial derivatives existing at the point (but not being continuous) and extend it by adding additional variables (as many as you want) so that the function is independent on them (say turn $f(x,y)=|xy|$ to $f(x,y,z,t,\ldots)=|xy|$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, my english is not as good. My question is about if we can reduce the number of partial derivatives that there exist in a ball and are continouous at $\hat{x}_0$, to number less than $n$ and greater than $0$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks, that answer my question.

Comment: ? Jorge S. My first and second comments said exactly the same! So I did understand correctly your question (but not your answer to my first comment).

Comment: @AnneBauval I think if you write out with care how the example for $n=2$ basically gives you an example for $n-2$ failing for $n=3$ or higher, that would be a good answer that should settle Jorge's curiosity.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you but his curiosity seems satisfied by Stinking Bishop's comment, which (though equivalent) he understood better than mine.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Maybe you could post that as an answer so this question doesn't remain unanswered?